# Not able to consume MTLS service on postman but it works in SOAP UI

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore, jks

I am trying to consume a MTLS service on postman. For this I had to generate the  crt and key files from the keystore jks file. In SOAP UI, I have the following setup:

[image: sopaui setup]But postman only accepts crt and key format type. I assumed I don't need to include anything regarding truststore. I ran the following commands to generate both the crt and key files from the jks:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore .\appcertkeystore -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

    winpty openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out my_store.key
    winpty openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nokeys -out my_key_store.crt
```

Then

included the values into postman as so:

[image: postman setup]

However I am getting the following error when sending the request:

Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

I am new to trustores and keystores so I don't know if I am overlooking something. What can the problem be?